# Should I work with latest android gradle and libraries version?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Please, I wish to know if working with the latest android Gradle and libraries version is a good idea; since all through my learning path, all starter code the instructors provided had old versions of Gradle and these libraries and instructed us not to update. So I wish to know if I should follow their advice or otherwise.

Thanks

Comment: *all starter code the instructors provided had old versions of Gradle and these libraries and instructed us not to update.* I guess no one will give you this kind of suggestions dependencies and libraries are eventually updated to make them efficient than earlier versions and also to cope with new versions of android.

Comment: To clarify, the instructors said if we did that, it may not work again

Comment: To make you clear for every update they make some of the old methods go deprecated and are replaced with new and advanced implementation to make the coding hassle free and effective. But coping with the change is a mess to lot of developers. But it is always advised to upgrade to new libraries when ruled out after knowing everything about that

Comment: I understand. thank you